# Getting SyntaxError for my csv reader code, even though I put in the correct column name

Tags: python, syntax-error, csvreader

My code:

```
import csv

def  searchProxy():

     csv_file = csv.reader(open ('C:/Users/Keanu/Documents/CSV/07-12-report.csv', 'r'))
     cardIdentifier = input('Enter proxy')

     for row CardIdentifier in csv_file:
         if Card Identifier == row[0]:
             print(row)

print ('Enter to search card identifier')
src = int(input ("Enter here: "))
```

I'm getting this `SyntaxError`:

```
File "C:\Users\Keanu\Documents\PythonProjects\main.py", line 8
    for row CardIdentifier in csv_file:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Process finished with exit code 1
```

`CardIdentifier` is the name of a column in my csv file, and I'm search through each row. What could be causing the error?

Comment: You can not spaces in your variable names.

Comment: I highly recommend programming in an IDE, like the free one PyCharm, so that it'll tell you about errors long before you even run the script. If you're not already doing that.

Comment: Using a IDE isn't going to help if you don't know the language or read the documentation. `for row CardIdentifier in csv_file:` ***is*** syntactically incorrect. I suggest you review the documentation on the [`for`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) statement as well on that of the [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader).

Comment: P.S. You're not even opening the CSV file properly — see the example in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def searchProxy():
     csv_file = csv.reader(open ('C:/Users/Keanu/Documents/CSV/07-12-report.csv', 'r'))
     cardIdentifier = input('Enter proxy')
     for row in csv_file:
         if cardIdentifier == row[0]: #I don't think row[0] as well I think it is row only
             print(row)
```

You aren't supposed to use space between variable name! You have so, many typos errors in your code as well.

You had wrote somewhere `cardIdentifier` and somewhere `CardIdentifier` which is completely different thing. Just remember main/one things, you can't give space in variable name, like `test csv` you can either do `test_csv` or `testcsv`, But not space!

Comment: Hey the code compile now, but nothing was showing when I enter my string, it just says:

Comment: Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Please tell me what you are trying to do, the I may help you!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have the variable `CardIdentifier` on the `for row` line.

You miswrote the variable name on the next line. The first letter is `c`, not `C`, and you added a space in it.

You also didn't indent the `if` line correctly.

```
     for row in csv_file:
        if cardIdentifier == row[0]:
            print(row)
```